# Je hais (à) vous parler

Tags: grammaire

Le 14 juillet 1680, Mme de Sévigné écrit :

> *Je hais* mortellement ***à*** vous parler de tout cela ; pourquoi m’en
> parlez-vous ? ma plume va comme une étourdie.

Est-ce correct d'écrire *haïr **à** vous parler* ? Ne dirait-on pas *haïr vous parler* ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dans le sens dans lequel on emploie le verbe haïr le plus fréquemment de nos  jours (abhorrer) on le construit avec *de* ou *pour* devant l'infinitif.

- Je le hais de m'avoir fait ça.
- Je le hais pour m'avoir fait ça.

Si l'infinitif est COD on peut le construire de façon directe :

- Je hais manger des tomates.
- Je hais vous parler<sup>1</sup>.

Il y a une contruction du verbe qui n'est plus vraiment utilisée de nos jours et qu'on peut trouver dans le [Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/ha%C3%AFr) :

> **Haïr à**, avec un infinitif. Avoir de la répugnance pour.
> "Je hais mortellement à vous parler de tout cela ; pourquoi m'en parlez-vous ? ma plume va comme une étourdie", Sévigné.
> "Tel qui hait à se voir peint en de faux portraits, Sans chagrin voit tracer ses véritables traits", Boileau, Épît.
> "Ils haïssent autant à les voir [les femmes] avec de la céruse sur le visage, qu'avec de fausses dents", La Bruyère.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>  Il faut cependant noter que « avoir horreur de » ou « détester » sont plus fréquents pour exprimer cette idée (j'ai horreur de manger des tomates/je déteste vous parler).</sup>

Answer (score -2):

''Hair'', ''abhorrer'' etc,  c'est déjà du vocabulaire de choix, tendance littéraire, comme pas commode à prononcer: diphtongue  a-i: ''Je vous hais'' = ''Je vous ai'' ? Commment, qu'avez-vous pour moi? = Confusion de même prononciation  //  Cas comparable avec ''aimer à'': ''J'aime à écrire beaucoup''. Nuance! Là, il n'y pas de ''de'' ou ''pour''. Et, ''j'aime écrire'' relève du style banal, jovial, commercial. Donc, la particule ''à'' sert à emphaser le sens: J'aime à...; je hais à faire telle et telle chose. ''à'', c'est fort, exception faite concernant ''partir'' ou ''partir pour qp.'' est plus fort que ''partir'à qp.'' // La particule ''de'' est coulante, agréable, idiomatique, ''à'', c'est incisif, c'est du sérieux, on ne s'amuse pas, on ne discute pas: Parler au curé, au chef mais parler avec sa femme, ses collégues et amis. // ''Ah, si vous continuez à me parler sur ce ton, je vais commencer à vous hair à vous fournir plus de détails sur  cette affaire.'' > On (entre-)voit la nuance des différents niveaux de langage: commercial = neutre = impersonnel <> personnel, amical, jovial >< sérieux, cassant, juridique, finie la plaisanterie.

Comment: *Je vous hais* ne *je vous ai* ne peuvent pas être confondus car ils se prononcent toujours différemment (liaison interdite / obligatoire). Le verbe *emphaser* n'existe pas (encore ?)